# Laravel 5 Encryption - Different values for same string given?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, encryption, laravel-5

I'm using Laravel 5, and for a project, for which one of the tenants is that emails stored in the system must be encrypted. I am using Laravel 5's `Crypt::` facade, and the relevant `encrypt()` and `decrypt()` methods.

The problem lies in that the encrypted value seems to differ, even if given the same string. At first I thought it could be to do with `VARCHAR` field max lengths, however both the hash values come back under the 255 length set on the field.

Take for example, this dump;

PHP

```
    $hash1 = 'eyJpdiI6InJFNTFkdktpVU9cL1wvRTJPVk94SURiUT09IiwidmFsdWUiOiJIZVh4Y1NyUGpVcTVFVTNSbWdUNnJCUWRHSGZTcnFTQWJKa1h0Q1wvMEVtZnFuM3dDeFwvXC9hdUs4enFXXC94dEJ0cSIsIm1hYyI6IjFjNjZjODFjMjI5NTQ0NmVhZDUwODQzODE0OTQ4NTdjMzAxNTQ5Y2ZjY2M4YzRiODU0ZjIwNDhmMDA0Yjc4OWQifQ';
    $hash2 = 'eyJpdiI6ImRBVWNKVTlJZVFmckk2T0c4cXNObFE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoidElqcE5TMUFwVHZXeW12R3hKMFVFWlR0WmgxOFRBbW5cL2V3dUJ6VndsdktLYjVGR2JQQWpSUUNUWDBJbU5OQWEiLCJtYWMiOiI3MjM3ODNiMzc0NDJlNDVhYzFkOTBmMjhhOTk0MTUyM2FlNzM5ZGE4ODE3MTJlMDM5NWZiMzViZjM5OTA0MGRhIn0=';
    $dump = [
    'hash1' => $hash1,
    'hash2' => $hash2,
    'string1' => Crypt::decrypt($hash1),
    'string2' => Crypt::decrypt($hash2)
    ];
    return $dump;
```

Dumped Object

```
hash1: "eyJpdiI6InJFNTFkdktpVU9cL1wvRTJPVk94SURiUT09IiwidmFsdWUiOiJIZVh4Y1NyUGpVcTVFVTNSbWdUNnJCUWRHSGZTcnFTQWJKa1h0Q1wvMEVtZnFuM3dDeFwvXC9hdUs4enFXXC94dEJ0cSIsIm1hYyI6IjFjNjZjODFjMjI5NTQ0NmVhZDUwODQzODE0OTQ4NTdjMzAxNTQ5Y2ZjY2M4YzRiODU0ZjIwNDhmMDA0Yjc4OWQifQ"
hash2: "eyJpdiI6ImRBVWNKVTlJZVFmckk2T0c4cXNObFE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoidElqcE5TMUFwVHZXeW12R3hKMFVFWlR0WmgxOFRBbW5cL2V3dUJ6VndsdktLYjVGR2JQQWpSUUNUWDBJbU5OQWEiLCJtYWMiOiI3MjM3ODNiMzc0NDJlNDVhYzFkOTBmMjhhOTk0MTUyM2FlNzM5ZGE4ODE3MTJlMDM5NWZiMzViZjM5OTA0MGRhIn0="
string1: "admin03@y..sef...iman.com"
string2: "admin03@y..sef...iman.com"
```

Dots are inputted in place of characters for privacy, but they are exactly the same. The only other thing I can possibly think about is maybe some kind of charset formatting?

Any help resolving this would be greatly appreciated!

Regards.

Comment: Wait, what's the issue then if the decrypted hashes end up being identical?

Comment: If the key is different, then the encrypted value will be different; and the keys shouldn't always be the same otherwise it becomes predictable and easily breakable. That's the whole point

Comment: @MarkBaker Apologies, I don't know much about encryption in general - I thought that the same value would be given both ways. The point was that these values had to be stored in a database table, but be a retrieval point for rows of data, I'll have to figure out another more feasible method now :).

Comment: Can you post your current query?  Why can't you select the value using a different column?

Comment: `'SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '#hashvalue' LIMIT 1` is effectively it, although using Laravel's Eloquent ORM. It's for password resetting, so the only viable option to guarantee that an email with a password reset token is sent to the right email address, is to match the user inputted email address against the `email` value. I have just tried to use `bcrypt()`, which from what I understand, is one way encryption, but the results still remain the same.

Comment: If this is for password storage, you don't want to encrypt the data, you want to hash it. You should use bcrypt() not because the result is always the same, but because it can't be reversed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand your question, it's why does the encrypted results differ, even with the same input and the same key?

(You mention these being hashes, but Crypt::encrypt() and decrypt() are for symmetric encryption)

[Laravel Crypt uses CBC mode by default](http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/109/setting-the-encryption-mode). That means it generates a random IV every time you encrypt something, to ensure the output is always different.

Without using a mode like CBC, you risk leaking information. If I know that `admin03@y..sef...iman.com` always encrypts to `eyJpdiI6InJFNTFkdktpVU9cL1wvRTJPVk94SURiUT09IiwidmFsdWUiOiJIZVh4Y1NyUGpVcTVFVTNSbWdUNnJCUWRHSGZTcnFTQWJKa1h0Q1wvMEVtZnFuM3dDeFwvXC9hdUs4enFXXC94dEJ0cSIsIm1hYyI6IjFjNjZjODFjMjI5NTQ0NmVhZDUwODQzODE0OTQ4NTdjMzAxNTQ5Y2ZjY2M4YzRiODU0ZjIwNDhmMDA0Yjc4OWQifQ`, then even without knowing your encryption key, I still know *something* about your messages (who it's being sent to, for example).

You can see a great example of the risk [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Electronic_Codebook_.28ECB.29).

Edit: If this is for password storage, you should not be using encrypt() and decrypt(). You should use bcrypt() or PBKDF2. Otherwise, assuming a compromise, an attacker could just decrypt all your users passwords.

Comment: Laravel's `Hash` facade has a convenient `make` method, so you just call `Hash::make($string)` when you want to generate e.g. a password for a User. That's also what the built-in `Auth` class uses to check passwords on submit.