# Laravel API having trouble logging in

Tags: php, laravel

I have the following 2 methods to create and login a user in my `API`. I cannot login the user. These files are in the `api.php` within the routes folder. If I leave off the `bcrypt($password)` within the `User::Create()` method it still seems to hash the password somehow does the `User::Create()` method automatically hash the password. I am wondering if it is getting double hashed somehow.

```
Route::post('/register', function( Request $request){
    $rules = [
        'name' => 'required|max:255|alpha_dash|unique:users',
        'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:6',
    ];
    $input = $request->only(
        'name',
        'email',
        'password',
        'password_confirmation'
    );
    $validator = Validator::make($input, $rules);
    if($validator->fails()) {
        $error = $validator->messages();
        return response()->json(['success'=> false, 'error'=> $error]);
    }

    $name = $request->name;
    $email = $request->email;
    $password = $request->password;
    $user = User::create(['name' => $name, 'email' => $email, 'password' => bcrypt($password), 'api_token' => md5($email)]);

    return response()->json(['success'=> true, 'data'=> $user]);

});

Route::post("/login", function (Request $request){

    $rules = [
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'password' => 'required',
    ];

    $input = $request->only('email', 'password');

    $validator = Validator::make($input, $rules);

    if($validator->fails()) {
        $error = $validator->messages();
        return response()->json(['success'=> false, 'error'=> $error]);
    }


        $email = $request->email;
        $password =  bcrypt($request->password);



    if(\Auth::Attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password])){
        ///How to get USER to return with Response
        return response()->json(['success' => true]);

    }else{
        return response()->json(['success' => false, 'error' => 'Invalid Credentials', 'password' => $password, 'email' => $email]);
    }

});
```

Comment: Did this come from the Laravel Auth controller?

Comment: No. I wrote this code in api.php within the routes folder.

Comment: If you didn't enable Auth then it shouldn't do any encryption. Is there a reason why you don't want to use the Auth controller instead? I did encounter the same problem before when I created a guest account login. The problem was that the saved encrypted password was not equal to the password encrypted during the login process. It seems that the encryption changes everytime you use it

Comment: I have both regular form based login and this api login. How to use Auth controller for both?

Comment: It seems this is what you need: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39197989/laravel-5-using-bcrypt-on-same-string-gives-different-values)

Comment: Not understanding how that helps.

Comment: you can check if you change your login from Auth attempt to hash:check instead. Also, you can just point your forms to the Auth controller instead of creating your own if all your users share the same table and there are no difference between them.

Comment: How are you calling these routes though? Are you sure you are not calling the default Laravel Auth routes?

Comment: I am calling them from an IOS application.

Comment: mysite.com/api/register

Comment: @hungrykoala I got this working by using Hash:check()

Comment: So the Hash::check worked for you?

Comment: Yes see where i posted below the solution. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is what i came up with to "log the user in".

```
Route::post("/login", function (Request $request){

    $rules = [
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'password' => 'required',
    ];

    $input = $request->only('email', 'password');

    $validator = Validator::make($input, $rules);

    if($validator->fails()) {
        $error = $validator->messages();
        return response()->json(['success'=> false, 'error'=> $error]);
    }


   $email = $request['email'];
   $password = $request['password'];
   $user = User::where('email', $email)->first();
    if($user){
       if(\Hash::check($password, $user->password)){
           return response()->json(['success' => true, 'user' => $user]);
       }else{
           return response()->json(['success' => false, 'error' => 'Invalid Credentials']);
       }
    }else{
        return response()->json(['success' => false, 'error' => 'Invalid Credentials']);
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You `bcrypt($request->password)` but if you `Auth::Attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password])`, laravel automatically hash the value.
So try in your login route just `$password =  $request->password;`

From the docs:

> The attempt method accepts an array of key / value pairs as its first argument. The values in the array will be used to find the user in your database table. So, in the example above, the user will be retrieved by the value of the email column. If the user is found, the hashed password stored in the database will be compared with the password value passed to the method via the array. You should not hash the password specified as the password value, since the framework will automatically hash the value before comparing it to the hashed password in the database. If the two hashed passwords match an authenticated session will be started for the user.

Comment: Tried that as well. I had to come up with a completely different solution.

Comment: I copied you code and it worked, without the bcrypt it retuned succes:true and with bcrypt error: "Invalid Credentials",

Comment: Will have to check again. Did you do that in the web routes or api routes file?

Comment: I tested it in the api.php file. Just make sure you bcrypt when creating but not when loggin in. It should work.