# Manual authentication always return false in laravel 5.5?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

I'm try to make manual authentication in laravel 5.5 but it always return false.
in path App\Http\Controllers AdminController looks like that.

```
public function loginPost()
{
    $remember = request()->has('remember') ? true : false;

    ////////////// Always return false /////////////
    dd(Auth::guard('user')->attempt(['username' => request('username'),
                'password' => request('password')], $remember));
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////

    if (Auth::guard('user')->attempt(['username' => request('username'),
                'password' => request('password')], $remember))


        return redirect('/');
    }
    return back();
}
```

Comment: is your password hashed?

Comment: yes in model i put public function setPasswordAttribute($pass) { $this->attributes['password'] = bcrypt($pass); } i try with it and without it. and same result and i can't even show errors in view

Comment: You could always `Auth::login($user);` if you are sure on the password, i.e. `$user = \App\User::where('username', request('username'))->firstOrFail(); if (\Hash::check(request('password'), $user->password)) { Auth::login($user) }`

Comment: try to `bcrypt` it in your `loginPost` too

Comment: same result unfortunately

Comment: i insert first row in table when making migration
User::insert([["name" => "Mohamed Elkomy","username" => "WhiteMonkey","email" => $email,"role_id" => 1,"password" => bcrypt($password),'created_at' => Carbon::now(),'updated_at' => Carbon::now(),]]); is it right way to hash password when insert record in database table ?

Comment: try to `User::where('password', bcrypt($password))->first();` using `php artisan tinker` if it exists, then you can login with it.

Comment: i try to show two passwords to be sure they are identical echo $user->password."<br>"; echo bcrypt(request('password'))."<br>"; but i find password from request change every time i refresh my page

Comment: Here is the [reason](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39198006/6901192)

Comment: btw, what is 'user' guard? can you please provide details about it?

Comment: thx for help guys .. i was change my password and forget it. Hash::check('secret', $hash1) from your link Ahmed Nour was a clue to me :D