# Laravel Password Encryption Parameters to decrypt the code

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, password-protection, password-encryption, password-hash

I have some different requirement, i don't want to decode the password, but i am building some other app based on SAME DATABASE for LOGIN so what i can do to "encrypt the password value so that it matches the backend password encrypted code".

I want to provide LOGIN from CODEIGNITOR app where data base is created by admin app in LARAVEL ... this is the issue...

So through CodeIgnitor if someone is LOGIN the password will be encrypted equivalent hash encrypted laravel application code.

**The Encrypted Password is**

```
$2y$10$cwd15HRgON0ytqkkV5F9zupfUOkqaii7fpbB9Kjd9I7W46LRYY0Km
```

**And the real PASSWOORD is**

```
123456
```

Please help...

Answer (score 3):

Caddy DZ's answer is right, but to better answer your question you should know that every time you generate a new password with bcrypt function, a new random salt is used.
This leads you to end up getting a different hash for the same password each time you generate one.

The only way you have to verify the correctness of the password, is to use a built-in php function called `password_verify`.
That function will hash your password (that you provide as a second argument) with the same salt that has been used to generate the stored password (the salt to use is stored in the password hash) you already have in the database:

```
$password = '123456';
$saved = 'your stored hash';

if (password_verify($password, $saved)) {
    echo 'Correct password.';
}
```

You can check the documentation about [password_verify](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php)

Comment: thanks :) Caddy answer is accurate as have read some more option and your answer is just solved my problem exactly :)

Comment: If the question is solved then do not forget to mark the correct answer!

Answer (score 2):

This is not standard encryption that can be decrypted, this is hashing which is only one (1) way encryption..
To make this work in, you need to use the same hashing algorithm between the two apps (Laravel and CodeIgniter)

For instance laravel uses `bcrypt` by default to hash the password, so you need to configure CodeIgniter to use the same or vice versa.

[bcrypt for codeigniter](https://github.com/dwightwatson/codeigniter-bcrypt)

Comment: Thanks i am looking for the "the same hashing algorithm" which you are saying **bcrypt**
but laraval code do have HASH KEY-how to use that???

Comment: added link to bcrypt for code igniter, it's builtin Laravel so there's nothing to install

Comment: thanks but its not generating the SAME encrypted PASSWORD with bcrypt....please refer in Question to see the Stored password with actual password string...

Comment: It's designed that way but still would work for both, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/39198006/5581565